An error occurred while loading the YAML build pipeline. The string must have at least one character. Parameter name: environmentName
i have deployed a node.js application in azure repos and i am trying to build a pipeline for it. i selected the nodejs environment in azure pipelines dropdown it has given me the below code . what are the changes i need to make here
An error occurred while loading the YAML build pipeline. The string must have at least one character.
Parameter name: environmentName
# Node.js Express Web App to Linux on Azure
# Build a Node.js Express app and deploy it to Azure as a Linux web app.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger:
- main

variables:

  # Azure Resource Manager connection created during pipeline creation
  azureSubscription: 'dfa61147-3cd3-4618-9610-ac53db20a0e0'

  # Web app name
  webAppName: ''

  # Environment name
  environmentName: ''

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '10.x'
      displayName: 'Install Node.js'

    - script: |
        npm install
        npm run build --if-present
        npm run test --if-present
      displayName: 'npm install, build and test'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: $(environmentName)
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy: '
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
              appType: webAppLinux
              appName: $(webAppName)
              runtimeStack: 'NODE|10.10'
              package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip
              startUpCommand: 'npm run start'


Even I faced the same error as yours when I kept webAppName and environmentName as empty.
# Web app name
  webAppName: ''

  # Environment name
  environmentName: ''

In order to resolve this error make sure you add the environment name and Web app name properly, Refer below:-
Replace  webAppName with the name of your Azure Web app where you want to deploy your code and environmentName with the name of the environment that Azure Devops will use to run the pipeline, You can keep its name same as your Azure Web app or add another name. These variables will be fetched in AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4 step as $(webAppName)
   # Web app name
  webAppName: 'expressappsid'

  # Environment name
  environmentName: 'expressappsid'

Complete yaml code for Express App:-
trigger:
- main

variables:

  azureSubscription: '81xxxxxxxxxx0a17'

  # Web app name
  webAppName: 'expressappsid'

  # Environment name
  environmentName: 'expressappsid'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '10.x'
      displayName: 'Install Node.js'

    - script: |
        npm install
        npm run build --if-present
        npm run test --if-present
      displayName: 'npm install, build and test'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: $(environmentName)
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy: expressappsid'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
              appType: webAppLinux
              appName: $(webAppName)
              runtimeStack: 'NODE|10.10'
              package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip
              startUpCommand: 'npm run start'


You can select either Node.js React Web App to Linux on Azure OR Node.js Express  Web App to Linux on Azure template > Select your subscription and login, then select the Node Azure Web app.
Make sure you select the correct Web app in the dropdown:-

Refer my SO Answer where I have outlined complete steps to Deploy NodeJs app from Azure Devops.
